# NdisFSendNetBufferLists causes BSoD when the adapter is being disabled

Tags: c, windows, networking, driver, ndis

I have a `NDIS 6.x LWF` driver that can capture and send packets on Windows. It's an update of WinPcap from NDIS 5 to NDIS 6.

This driver receives the packet data from the user-mode applications and send them out using `NdisFSendNetBufferLists` (See Line 631 in https://github.com/nmap/npcap/blob/master/packetWin7/npf/npf/Write.c). I fount out that if when the packet sending is going on, I disable the corresponding adapter in `Network Connections` (aka `ncpa.cpl`). Then the system got a blue screen. I analyzed the minidump file and the output is below:

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff80745e9de30, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffa38002702de0, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for npf.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  14267.1000.amd64fre.rs1_release.160213-0213

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  OptiPlex 7010

SYSTEM_SKU:  OptiPlex 7010

SYSTEM_VERSION:  01

BIOS_VENDOR:  Dell Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  A14

BIOS_DATE:  06/10/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  09PR9H

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A01

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff80745e9de30

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffa38002702de0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
ndis!NdisFSendNetBufferLists+c0
fffff807`45e9de30 4c8b5818        mov     r11,qword ptr [rax+18h]

CONTEXT:  ffffa38002702de0 -- (.cxr 0xffffa38002702de0)
rax=6b49534e02130018 rbx=6b49534e02130019 rcx=0000000000000001
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=ffffd50728240030 rdi=ffffd5072c4ac8d0
rip=fffff80745e9de30 rsp=ffffa380027037e0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000060001 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
ndis!NdisFSendNetBufferLists+0xc0:
fffff807`45e9de30 4c8b5818        mov     r11,qword ptr [rax+18h] ds:002b:6b49534e`02130030=????????????????
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: c79

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3a,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1B'00000000 (cache) 1B'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  EapolLogin.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  AKISN0W-PC

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  02-26-2016 13:42:06.0762

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff807476f67f8 to fffff80745e9de30

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffa380`027037e0 fffff807`476f67f8 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffffd507`3a613570 : ndis!NdisFSendNetBufferLists+0xc0
ffffa380`02703860 fffff803`8c698c05 : ffffd507`3a6134a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 fffff680`00003140 : npf!NPF_Write+0x214 [j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\write.c @ 324]
ffffa380`027038d0 fffff803`8c69840a : ffffd507`39edba60 ffffd507`3a6134a0 ffffd507`2871aef0 ffffa380`02703b80 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1a5
ffffa380`02703990 fffff803`8c3d2f83 : ffff8208`1164b160 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtWriteFile+0x67a
ffffa380`02703a90 00007fff`94c21034 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`0014e248 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007fff`94c21034


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  8de63a100febe6f9f89153a5a9abc9ba86d452de

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  c12fe9b8d789ae102dec8036452ef91cdcd180b3

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  bccfea03237cfde6486a55b63bb95e3341833378

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
npf!NPF_Write+214 [j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\write.c @ 324]
fffff807`476f67f8 8b6c2478        mov     ebp,dword ptr [rsp+78h]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  78246c8b

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\write.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\write.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  324

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  
   320:                         NDIS_DEFAULT_PORT_NUMBER,
   321:                         SendFlags);
   322:                 }
   323: 
>  324:             numSentPackets ++;
   325:         }
   326:         else
   327:         {
   328:             //
   329:             // no packets are available in the Transmit pool, wait some time. The 


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  npf!NPF_Write+214

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: npf

IMAGE_NAME:  npf.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  56c2d58e

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffa38002702de0 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  214

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_npf!NPF_Write

BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_npf!NPF_Write

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x3B_npf!NPF_Write

TARGET_TIME:  2016-02-26T02:30:30.000Z

OSBUILD:  14267

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-02-13 20:56:11

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160213-0213

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.14267.1000.amd64fre.rs1_release.160213-0213

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 127c9

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x3b_npf!npf_write

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {2eb5e15e-9853-313b-618d-2ac277a2bfb5}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

The source code line pointed in the above dump analysis report is not very precise. It's actually the line above `numSentPackets ++;`

So the below code triggers BSoD.

```
NdisFSendNetBufferLists(Open->AdapterHandle,
                    pNetBufferList,
                    NDIS_DEFAULT_PORT_NUMBER,
                    SendFlags);
```

It's understandable the disable behavior of the adapter causes this BSoD, as if you have disabled an adapter, you should fail to send packets to it. I can't stop a user disable his adapter when using my driver. But I think the only thing should happen in that condition is failing the sending action. A BSoD is too much.

So, what I want to know is what's the correct way to let my driver prevent this according to NDIS's design? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

I modified my code as Jeffrey suggested, but the same BSoD still happens. My code is at: https://github.com/nmap/npcap/commit/f68b20fca345ca195d0862856ed8ac6c0f65c957

---

**UPDATE 2**

Hi. I still have two questions.

1) Why don't set `me->PausePending = TRUE;` in the else branch of `FilterPause`? Does returning `NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS` in `FilterPause` mean something? What if my driver still call `NdisFSendNetBufferLists` (this is controlled by user-mode app) after returning `NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS` in `FilterPause`?

2) Should I set in `Open->PausePending = TRUE;` in the `NPF_Restart` (`FilterRestart`) routine?

Comment: Have you tried using Driver Verifier on your driver? It sounds to me like your driver is missing some sort of event handler. Like the "device disconnected" event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a NIC is disabled:

1. TCPIP (and others) will stop sending packets to your filter driver.
2. Your filter driver gets a `FilterPause` call.
3. Your filter driver gets a `FilterDetach` call.

After you complete step #2, you're not allowed to originate new NBLs.
After you complete step #3, you're not allowed to originate *anything* (OIDs, status indications, etc.) and you can delete your filter module context.

I glanced at the GitHub code, and I noticed that the `NPF_Pause` routine is a no-op.  That is the cause of this bug.  An LWF driver that originates NBLs *must* handle pause.  One typical implementation of `FilterPause` is something like this:

```
NDIS_STATUS FilterPause(. . .)
{
    NDIS_STATUS status;

    AcquireDatapathLock();

    if (me->NumberOfOriginatedSendPackets > 0 ||
        me->NumberOfOriginatedReceivePackets > 0)
    {
         me->PausePending = TRUE;
         status = NDIS_STATUS_PENDING;
    }
    else
    {
         status = NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    ReleaseDatapathLock();
    return status;
}
```

Your NBL completion handler should complete the pause, when the number of originated NBLs drops to zero:

```
VOID CompleteSendNbl(. . .)
{
    BOOLEAN CompletePause = FALSE;
    AcquireDatapathLock();

    me->NumberOfOriginatedSendPackets -= 1;

    if (me->NumberOfOriginatedSendPackets == 0 &&
        me->PausePending)
    {
        CompletePause = TRUE;
    }

    ReleaseDatapathLock();

    if (CompletePause)
    {
        NdisFPauseComplete(. . .);
    }
}
```

And finally, make sure to not originate new NBLs once you're pausing:

```
NDIS_STATUS TrySendPacket(. . .)
{
    NDIS_STATUS status;
    AcquireDatapathLock();

    if (me->PausePending)
    {
         status = NDIS_STATUS_PAUSED;
    }
    else
    {
         status = NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
         me->NumberOfOriginatedSendPackets++;
    }

    ReleaseDatapathLock();

    if (status == NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
         . . .
         NdisFSendNetBufferLists(. . .);
    }
}
```

Of course, there are several ways to optimize the above.  But first get it working.  Then maybe make it faster if it's too slow for your needs.

Comment: Hi. I modified exactly as your suggestion here: https://github.com/nmap/npcap/commit/f68b20fca345ca195d0862856ed8ac6c0f65c957. But the same BSoD still happens. Can you examine where I'm doing wrong in the code?

Comment: The code looks right... while the new BSoD happens, what are the values of PausePending and TransmitPendingPackets?  Was NPF_DetachAdapter called yet?  BTW you don't need InterlockedXxx if all modifications are done under spinlock.

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Why don't set ``me->PausePending = TRUE;`` in the ``else`` branch of ``FilterPause``? Does returning ``NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS`` in ``FilterPause`` mean something? What if my driver still call ``NdisFSendNetBufferLists`` (this is controlled by user-mode app) after returning ``NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS`` in ``FilterPause``? 2) Should I set in ``Open->PausePending = TRUE;`` in the ``NPF_Restart`` routine?